# XML to SQL Columns and value

Tags: sql, xml

I have this xml value as a column in a table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<table>
  <id>{44f2e878-64a6-4217-acba-2d986cbb0f93}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="wc_Bin" value="BIN-2" type="System.String" />
        <column name="wc_replacebin" value="BIN-3" type="System.String" />
        <column name="wc_client" value="70360" type="System.String" />
        <column name="ec_weight" value="150" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="wc_Bin" value="BIN-3" type="System.String" />
        <column name="wc_replacebin" value="Bin-1" type="System.String" />
        <column name="wc_client" value="1000058" type="System.String" />
        <column name="ec_weight" value="250" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="wc_Bin" value="Bin-1" type="System.String" />
        <column name="wc_replacebin" value="BIN-2" type="System.String" />
        <column name="wc_client" value="1000006" type="System.String" />
        <column name="ec_weight" value="100" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="3" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
  <key>DefaultKey</key>
  <total>0</total>
  <data />
  <parameters />
</table>
```

I want column name from `<column name="wc_bin">` and its value from `value=""` attribute. Desired output is:

```
wc_Bin   Replace_Bin   wc_Client    ec_weight
----------------------------------------------
Bin-2    Bin-3         70360          350
bin-3    Bin-1         1000058        250
Bin-1    Bin-2         100006         100
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Further do marc's comment, you can add this tag by an [edit] of your question and adding an appropriate tag in the tag section of the question.